# Pivot-table with list of data frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I've got a list called  `means` of data frames (column 1 is an activity name, column 2 is the corresponding duration) that looks like this:

```
> means
[[1]]
             X$activity  X$netTime
1               bolting  173.69014
2    boltingPreparation   13.70000
3 boltingRepositionning   18.17647
4        cutPreparation   26.66667


[[2]]
             X$activity   X$netTime
1               bolting   201.03297
2    boltingPreparation    34.10000
3 boltingRepositionning    22.72857
4               nonProd     0.00000
```

and I'd like to collapse this list in a 'pivot-table' way as follows:

```
> my.data.frame
               activity  1          2
1               bolting  173.69014  201.03297
2    boltingPreparation  13.70000   34.10000
3 boltingRepositionning  18.17647   22.72857
4        cutPreparation  26.66667   NA
5               nonProd  NA         0.00000
```

I feel like an `lapply` function might help, but don't really know where to start ...

**Related question**: how could I extract as a vector, all the `{activity,netTime}` tuples where (say) `activity == 'bolting'` across all indexes of the list `means`?

Comment: In your example, there is no column named `refined_activity`.  Perhaps `sapply(means, function(x) x[x$'X$activity'=='bolting',1])`

Comment: Sorry, I simplified the column names for simlicity's sake, `refined_activity` should read `activity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most easy-to-generalize solution that I can think of is to use `melt` and `dcast` from "reshape2", like this:

```
> library(reshape2)
> dcast(melt(means, id.vars = "X$activity"), `X$activity` ~ L1, value.var = "value")
             X$activity         1         2
1               bolting 173.69014 201.03297
2    boltingPreparation  13.70000  34.10000
3 boltingRepositionning  18.17647  22.72857
4        cutPreparation  26.66667        NA
5               nonProd        NA   0.00000
```

Using `melt` should also help your extracting needs -- just see the output of `melt(means, id.vars = "X$activity")` to get a sense of how having your data in a "long" form facilitates subsetting.

You could also do this in base R with:

```
> A <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(means), function(x) cbind(ind = x, means[[x]])))
> reshape(A, direction = "wide", idvar = "X$activity", timevar = "ind")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try `merge`

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by='X$activity', all=TRUE), means)
#                 X$activity X$netTime.x X$netTime.y
# 1               bolting   173.69014   201.03297
# 2    boltingPreparation    13.70000    34.10000
# 3 boltingRepositionning    18.17647    22.72857
# 4        cutPreparation    26.66667          NA
# 5               nonProd          NA     0.00000
```